# How to show my checkbox out of it's parent div?

Tags: html, css

First of all, I want to let you know that this task should be built using HTML & CSS only.

Secondly, I have to put [from 'sun' div to 'neck'div] as a sibilings to the checkbox in order to control it by css, and now the problem that How to show my checkbox out of it's parent div which is the 'outerCircle'.

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60%;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.day {
  background-color: #F2D16D;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 70px;
  width: 12%;
  height: 10%;
  top: -15px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 3px#F2D16D;
}

.moon {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  box-shadow: -12px 2px 0 8px #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 9px 6px #E1E1E1);
}

.outerCircle {
  /* top: -50%; */
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #46A679;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.innerCircle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 210%;
  height: 795%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 205%;
  left: -65%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.sun {
  background-color: #F2D16D;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 120%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  top: 280%;
}

.catBody {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #E4774F;
  height: 460%;
  width: 120%;
  top: 180px;
  right: 40px;
  transform: translate(0%, 10%);
}

.leftear,
.rightear {
  position: relative;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
}

.leftear {
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid #E4774F;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 194%;
}

.rightear {
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #E4774F;
  left: -40px;
  bottom: 334%;
}

.leftEye {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 220%;
  left: 10%;
}

.rightEye {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 280%;
  left: 55%;
}

.noise {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  /* z-index: 1; */
  width: 3%;
  height: 2%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 410px;
  left: 245px;
}

.neck {
  position: absolute;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  top: 390;
  left: -40px;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  border-top: 120px solid white;
}


/* switch section */

.button input {
  /* Remember: this is to clean the shape of the radio button */
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 120px;
  top: -115;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #47AB84;
  border-radius: 190px;
  transition: .7s;
}


/* internal circle */

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #FBE26C;
  transition: all .7s;
}

.round:before {
  top: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #65E3B5;
}


/* Animate the switch */

input:checked+.slider::before {
  transform: translateX(140px);
}

#select1:checked~.innerCircle {
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

#select1:checked~.sun {
  background-color: white;
  left: 0%;
}

#select1:checked~.leftEye {
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  /* height: 60%; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 220%;
  /* left: 10%; */
}

#select1:checked~.rightEye {
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  /* height: 60%; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 230%;
  /* left: 55%; */
}

.catBody:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #E4774F;
  height: 460%;
  width: 120%;
  top: 200px;
  /* right: 30px; */
  transform: translate(0%, 10%);
}

.catBody:hover~.leftear {
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid #E4774F;
  /* left: 110px; */
  bottom: 150%;
}

.catBody:hover~.rightear {
  border-top: 70px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #E4774F;
  /* left: -30px; */
  bottom: 280%;
}

.catBody:hover~.rightEye {
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  /* height: 60%; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 230%;
  /* left: 60%; */
}

.catBody:hover~.leftEye {
  height: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 15%;
  /* height: 60%; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 220%;
  /* left: 15%; */
}

#select1:checked~.catBody:hover~.rightEye {
  width: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  bottom: 280%;
  /* left: 55%; */
}

#select1:checked~.catBody:hover~.leftEye {
  width: 15%;
  height: 60%;
  /* left: 10%; */
}
```

```html
<article role="img">
  <div class="day"></div>
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <div class="whole">
    <div class="outerCircle">
      <label class="button" for="select1">
        <input id="select1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
        <div class="innerCircle"></div>
        <div class="sun"></div>
        <div class="catBody"></div>
        <div class="leftear"></div>
        <div class="rightear"></div>
        <div class="leftEye"></div>
        <div class="rightEye"></div>
        <div class="noise"></div>
        <div class="neck"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

I had to put the divs and the checkbox inside it
because the outer circle should above all and the over flow of the 'catBody' should be behind the 'outerCircle' as shown in the picture,
and I tried to use z-index but it didn't work with me, because it effected on hover work. How do I deal with it?

[image: This should be the final picture]

Comment: You missed out the entire CSS. Please do add it in.

Comment: @Gosi Yes, now done!